# Type Mismatch in scala case match

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to create multiple dataframes in a single foreach, using spark, as below

I get values delivery and click out of `row.getAs("type")`, when I try to print them.

```
val check = eachrec.foreach(recrd => recrd.map(row => {
  row.getAs("type") match {
    case "delivery" => val delivery_data = delivery(row.get(0).toString,row.get(1).toString)
    case "click" => val click_data = delivery(row.get(0).toString,row.get(1).toString)
    case _ => "not sure if this impacts"
}})
)
```

but getting below error:

> Error:(41, 14) type mismatch;  found   : String("delivery")  required: Nothing
>               case "delivery" => val delivery_data = delivery(row.get(0).toString,row.get(1).toString)
>                    ^

My plan is to create dataframe using `todf()` once I create these individual delivery objects referenced by delivery_data and click_data by:

```
delivery_data.toDF() and click_data.toDF().
```

1. Please provide any clue regarding the error above (in match case).
2. How can I create two df's using todf() in val check?

Answer (score 0):

`val` declarations make your first 2 `case`s return type to be `unit`, but in the third case you return a `String`

for instance, here the `z` type was inferred by the compiler, `Unit`:

```
def x = {
    val z: Unit = 3 match {
      case 2 => val a = 2
      case _ => val b = 3
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to cast this match clause to String.
row.getAs("type").toString